# PyQt4 is not installing

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, pyqt4, spyder

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install PyQt4
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- pyqt4

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I want to install PyQt4 as my project is built on PyQt4 but when going to install it showing above error. I don't want to install pyqt5

conda install PyQt=4
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- pyqt=4

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
showing above error while installing PtQt4

Answer (score 0):

**Please note:** pyqt-4.x is not actively maintained anymore in default and conda-forge channels. Therefore **I highly recommend not trying to install it into an existing environment**!

---

You can get pyqt-4.x by using the specifier pyqt=4. So in principle the command <s>`conda install pyqt=4`</s> would work. However this command could potentially cause problems due to lack of maintenance of the pyqt-4.x version in conda-forge, so please consider installing it into a new environment:

```
conda create -n <new-environment-name> -c conda-forge pyqt=4
```